# Getting actual type from an exception thrown in base class

Tags: c#, exception, inheritance

I have a series of classes in my application set up like follows:

```
abstract class Foo<TYPE> where TYPE : new()
{
    public void Error() 
    {
        List<TYPE> foo = null;
        foo.Add(new TYPE());
    }
}

class Bar : Foo<int>
{

}
```

When the call to `Bar.Error()` throws an exception, the stack trace simply reports it as being in `Foo'1.Error()`.   I know exactly *why* it does that, but I need to know that it was a `Bar` object actually throwing the error.   How can I derive that from the `Exception` object that gets thrown?

Comment: Can you modify `Bar` to override `Error` (and have it just call `base.Error()` and then see the stack trace? Or do you not have access to that source?

Comment: @JohnGibb - I could, but I'd have to do that for each child of `Foo`, of which there's currently five or so.  It's doable, but hard to maintain long term.

Comment: Try looking at `exception.TargetSite.DeclaringType` and `exception.TargetSite.ReflectedType`, one of those might show you the actual type but I'm not sure, so I don't want to submit this as an answer

Comment: I tested those two suggestions and neither worked, FYI

Comment: If you can modify `Foo`, I'd validate the value ahead of time and throw an exception. You get the added advantage of having `T` in that context.

Comment: @Magus - Yeah, that's what I ended up doing.  Between that and Jon's suggestion of other logging, I think I can track this down now.  Doesn't help for unexpected errors, but I can watch for the expected ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, just from an exception you don't control. There's no indication in the exception what instance happened to have a method executing when the exception was generated.

I would suggest using a debugger (so that you can break if the exception is thrown) and/or using more diagnostic logging. (For example, log the type of `this` at the start of the method.)

---

**Original answer, when the method itself directly threw the exception**

(Keeping this for posterity - it might be useful to others.)

You *could* use the `Source` property, or perhaps the `Data` property to record the name of the type or the instance. For example:

```
abstract class Foo<TYPE>
{
    public void Error() 
    {
        throw new Exception("Whoops") { Data = {{ "Instance", this }} };
    }
}
```

... then use:

```
catch (Exception e)
{
    var instance = e.Data["instance"];
    // Use the instance
}
```

This is a pretty odd use, however. It may well be more appropriate to throw your own custom exception type which *explicitly* knows about the instance that generated it.

Comment: I wasn't very explicit in the question, but there's not *supposed* to be an error there.  I'm just having a hard time tracking it down since I don't know which child class to focus on.  Edited to include a system-generated exception.

Comment: @Bobson: Oh. That changes the question completely. And no, there's no way of knowing that. I suggest debugging or more diagnostic logging.

Comment: Disappointing.  Not surprising, but it definitely makes this harder to track down.  Thanks!

Comment: @Bobson: Just as a bit of possibly helpful information for avoiding the problem: A compositional design, since it generally has no hierarchy, doesn't have this problem. The class in question is concretely itself, as is it's owner.

Answer (score 0):

You could try writing a custom Exception type that has a Type property, something like

```
public class CustomException : Exception {
    public Type ExceptionSourceType{get;set;}
}


abstract class Foo<TYPE>
{
    public void Error() 
    {
        var exception = new CustomException ("Whoops");
        exception.ExceptionSourceType = this.GetType();
        throw exception;
    }
}
```

Then if you specifically catch those types of errors you can easily access the property

```
catch(CustomException ex){
    var sourceType = ex.ExceptionSourceType;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question - I'm not actually throwing the exception, just trying to track down a system one.